# java error in "rosmake roboearth"

Tags: ros, roboearth, compilation, java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys!

I'm on a problem trying to compile roboearth package. I've follow the instruction posted on http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth, using rosinstall to download the package. When i try to compile the package with: "rosmake roboearth" i'll got a lot of error, i think that are related to some java problems.
Here are the logs:

```
    /home/prisma/fuerte_workspace/stacks/knowrob/json_prolog/src/java/edu/tum/cs/ias/knowrob/json_prolog/PrologBindings.java:80: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : variable JSONUtils
  location: class edu.tum.cs.ias.knowrob.json_prolog.PrologBindings
                    if(JSONUtils.isArray(bdg)) {
                       ^
  /home/prisma/fuerte_workspace/stacks/knowrob/json_prolog/src/java/edu/tum/cs/ias/knowrob/json_prolog/PrologBindings.java:82: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : variable JSONArray
  location: class edu.tum.cs.ias.knowrob.json_prolog.PrologBindings
                        Term[] objs = JSONQuery.decodeJSONArray(JSONArray.fromObject(bdg));
                                                                ^
  /home/prisma/fuerte_workspace/stacks/knowrob/json_prolog/src/java/edu/tum/cs/ias/knowrob/json_prolog/PrologBindings.java:90: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : variable JSONUtils
  location: class edu.tum.cs.ias.knowrob.json_prolog.PrologBindings
                    } else if(JSONUtils.isObject(bdg)) {
                              ^
  /home/prisma/fuerte_workspace/stacks/knowrob/json_prolog/src/java/edu/tum/cs/ias/knowrob/json_prolog/PrologBindings.java:91: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : variable JSONObject
  location: class edu.tum.cs.ias.knowrob.json_prolog.PrologBindings
                        Term obj = JSONQuery.decodeJSONValue(JSONObject.fromObject(bdg));
                                                             ^
  /home/prisma/fuerte_workspace/stacks/knowrob/json_prolog/src/java/edu/tum/cs/ias/knowrob/json_prolog/PrologBindings.java:94: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : variable JSONUtils
  location: class edu.tum.cs.ias.knowrob.json_prolog.PrologBindings
                    } else if(JSONUtils.isString(bdg)) {
                              ^
  /home/prisma/fuerte_workspace/stacks/knowrob/json_prolog/src/java/edu/tum/cs/ias/knowrob/json_prolog/PrologBindings.java:97: cannot find symbol
  symbol  : variable JSONUtils
  location: class edu.tum.cs.ias.knowrob.json_prolog.PrologBindings
                    } else if(JSONUtils.isNumber(bdg)) {
                              ^
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and ros fuerte release.

Any suggestions??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55026/java-error-in-%22rosmake-roboearth%22/) by [pacifica](https://answers.ros.org/users/1187/pacifica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2013-02-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have all rosdeps installed? It looks like libjson-java is missing. You can check with 'rosdep check knowrob' given that rosdep is set up correctly.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pacifica](https://answers.ros.org/users/1187/pacifica/) on 2013-02-12**:
Thanks a lot!! rosdep resolved my problems, i miss libjson!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For installation and compiling I figured the following (buggy or undocumented) issues:

```
sudo apt-get install swi-prolog
sudo apt-get install libjson-java
sudo apt-get install libjson-glib-dev
sudo apt-get install swi-prolog-odbc

CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/lib:/usr/share/java/*:./lib/:./lib/*:."

find ./ -iname *.java -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i "s/import de.tum.in.fipm.kipm.gui.visualisation.applets.CommunicationVisApplet;/import edu.tum.cs.ias.knowrob.vis.applets.CommunicationVisApplet;/g" {} \;
```

The last one replaces wrong includes of this CommunicationVisApplet which came with my roblib source version (r2235 from ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/)

---

Originally posted by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) with karma: 287 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1